# Adding ZSH alias

Tags: git, alias, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm a complete beginner with this. I'm trying to add this command as ZSH alias (I guess that is what I'm trying).

`git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d`

I've tried adding this line:

`alias delete-local-branches="git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d"`

After I source the updated file in iTerm, I get this:

```
~ source ~/.zshrc
-='cd -'
...=../..
....=../../..
.....=../../../..
......=../../../../..
1='cd -'
2='cd -2'
3='cd -3'
4='cd -4'
5='cd -5'
6='cd -6'
7='cd -7'
8='cd -8'
9='cd -9'
_='sudo '
afind='ack -il'
...

rd=rmdir
run-help=man
which-command=whence
```

Clearly, is not the expected result. 
Any help on how to add that to have the ability to autocomplete and use it as an alias?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use an alias; define a function instead.

Comment: What is the difference @chepner? 
I've tried changing the quotes and works as expected. Thanks @phd

Comment: Defining a function doesn't require any quotes that will conflict with quotes in the body of the function, it allows you to parameterize the command if needed, and is executed like any other command, rather than being a pure textual replacement in a command line.

Comment: @sebazelonka: The double quote after `egrep -v` closes the opening double quote just before `git`.

Comment: It's funny that the first alias I needed to create to use in iTerm was exactly the same git commands to delete local merged branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a function definition in your `.zshrc` file instead.

```
delete-local-branches () {
  git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the problem is with quoting. You have this part quoted:

```
alias delete-local-branches="git branch --merged | egrep -v "
```

then unquoted `(^\*|master|dev)`, and then quoted tail

```
" | xargs git branch -d"
```

My advice is to try to use different quotes:

```
alias delete-local-branches='git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d'
```

or escape internal quotes:

```
alias delete-local-branches="git branch --merged | egrep -v \"(^\*|master|dev)\" | xargs git branch -d"
```